# Matching all urls using router.all() method of Express and using Angular ui-router in the same time

Tags: node.js, express

**Problem solved. See the answer for details.**

I've written authentication part of my app long ago (there are a few jquery ajax calls), now I moved away from jQuery to Angular, so I won't be using Express.js for routing anymore.

I used to match `"/"` (localhost) like that.

```
router.get('/', csrfProtection, indexOnly, indexController.index);
```

I'll be using ui-router, so I will only serve one index.html file and angular will handle the rest. But I don't want to rewrite everything in the index page, so I want to make an exception for that.

If a user visits homepage, I check whether they're logged in or not. If they aren't, regular login page gets rendered, `(frontend/index)`. If they are logged in and try to visit main page (localhost), they get redirected to `/feed`. `indexOnly` checks that and `csrfProtection`, you know, protects from csrf. I only need two of these to work on index if the user is not logged in.

Here's indexController.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  res.render('frontend/index', {
    csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
  });
};
```

How can I do that? I tried a little but I couldn't do it. It turned into an unlimited loop, I guess.

index.js (Router)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var indexController = require('../../controllers/frontend/indexController');
var indexOnly = require('../../app').indexOnly;
var csrf = require('csurf');
var csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: true
});

router.all('/*', function(req,res,next) {
  if(req.originalUrl == '/') {
    router.get('/', csrfProtection, indexOnly, indexController.index);
  } else {
    res.sendFile('views/index.html', {
      root : __dirname
    });
  }
});
```

If I use it like below, index page works but then I get 403 forbidden for angular part.

```
router.get('/', csrfProtection, indexOnly, indexController.index);

router.all('/*', function(req,res,next) {
  if(req.originalUrl == '/') {
    next();
  } else {
    res.sendFile('../../views/index5.html', {
      root : __dirname
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Okay, I solved my problem. Solution is below.**

The problem was that I wanted to both keep my old jQuery/Express.js stack to serve index.jade file for unlogged/unregistered users and serve all routes using Angular ui-router.

Here's the full index.js (Router) file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var indexController = require('../../controllers/frontend/indexController');
var indexOnly = require('../../app').indexOnly;

var csrf = require('csurf');
var csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: true
});

var path = require('path');

router.get('/', csrfProtection, indexOnly, indexController.index);

router.all('/*', function(req,res,next) {
  if(req.originalUrl == '/') {
    next(); // it doesn't do anything, just allows the route above to work
  } else {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('views/index.html'));
  }
});
```